# ¿Cómo reemplazo el símbolo de un valor en una gráfica?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráficas

Tengo valores continuos, es decir, tengo 0 totales y valores en decimales que van desde 0.01. Necesito que únicamente los ceros resalten de manera diferente a un círculo en mi gráfica, pueden ser una "equis". Saben como lograrlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
g <- ggplot(data = Strongylocentrotus_purpuratus, aes(x = Años, y = Latitud, size = Densidad, color = Densidad)) + #color para cambiar las burbujas
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5, aes(size = Densidad)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 11) + #cambiar el número de valores en el eje de las x
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12))
g
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas definir la dimensión `shape` en función del valor de `Densidad == 0`. Primero unos datos sintéticos similares en estructura a los tuyos:

```
library(tidyverse)

Strongylocentrotus_purpuratus <- data.frame(Años = sample(2004:2020, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                                            Latitud = sample(23:33, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                                            Densidad = sample(0:50, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

Luego simplemente hay que definir la dimensión `aes(shape=Densidad == 0)`, y por último configurar la forma del punto para las dos estados mediante `scale_shape_manual()`:

```
Strongylocentrotus_purpuratus %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Años, 
              y = Latitud, 
              size = Densidad, 
              color = Densidad)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5, 
               aes(shape=Densidad == 0)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 11) + 
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 4)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 12))
```

La imagen resultado es solo ilustrativa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posiblemente también te convenga aumentar el tamaño para que resalten más las cruces, por ejemplo así: `size = ifelse(Densidad==0,50, Densidad)`